# What is the relation between the material conditional in logic and conditionals that we use every day?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, language

The material conditional has a truth-value of T in every case except where the antecedent proposition is true and the consequent is false. However, this means that many conditionals are true (if only vacuously so), that we would never use on a day to day basis. Is there some analysis demarcating ordinary language conditionals as a subset of material conditionals that can shed any light on this issue, or are we, as of now, limited to saying that vacuously true statements are true but useless to everyday life?

Comment: Some contemporary multi-value logics evaluate a conditional with a false antecedent to "null." The choice of true is somewhat arbitrary but given the law of the excluded middle, you have to pick either true or false.

Comment: It is strange though that in ordinary speech we would say that a conditional such as "If Budapest is a neighborhood in London then Budapest is in England" is true, while one such as "If grass is blue then I am a donkey's mother" is false. In both cases the antecedent and consequent are both false but the first conditional is intuitively true while the other is false. Is this simply a case where our intuition is flawed, or is there some deeper disconnect between ordinary language and logic?

Comment: I think it's more of a confusion about **what** logic is and does. Logic is not best understood as a translation for normal speech but rather as a formal system for thinking through problems that is more precise than normal speech. But the precision comes at a price -- bivalency, etc., have to be introduced in ways that lose information or force us to draw conclusions that are not yet definite.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, and definitely explains why it is difficult to reconcile ordinary language with first order logic. With that said, how _should_ we analyze ordinary language conditionals and other ordinary language "connectives" if we cannot use formal logic as a tool?

Comment: When material, you can translate the if statements differently, say as biconditionals, or you can translate them as conjunctions.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this explanation of Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486425339) (1967 - Dover reprint) [pag.10 - footnote 12] is a good short elucidation of the "formalization" of conditional in a truth-functional setting :

> The ordinary usage certainly requires that "If **A**, then **B**" to be true when **A** and **B** are both true, and to be false when **A** is true but **B** is false. So only our choice for T in the third and fourth lines [of the truth-table entered for **A** and **B**, i.e. the lines F-T and F-F] can be questioned. But if we changed T to F in both these lines, we would simply get a synonym for **∧** ["and"]; in the third line only, for **↔** [i.e. the *bi-conditional*]. If we changed T to F in the fourth line only, we would loose the useful property of our implication that "If **A**, then **B**" and "If not **B**, then not **A**" are true under the same circumstances [...].

The truth-functional definition of propositional *connectives* is a "model" that in some cases "fit" quite well with our usage in natural language (negation, disjunction, conjunction) and not so well in other cases (conditional).

When we assert a sentence **A** we are expressing the fact that we "judge it" to be *true*.

Thus, asserting the *conditional* **A → B** means to "judge" it *true*.

When mathematicians (like Frege) introduced the truth-functional conncetive , they have in  mind one characteristic property of the connective, viz., the rule of modus ponens. With this rule, we assert **A → B** and **A**; in this case, the first assertion "exclude" the case when **A** is *true* and **B** *false*, while the second assertion "exclude" the two cases where **A** is *false*.

Thus, we have only one possibility left : **B** *true*, and this is what we expected.

In our "ordinary" use of the language we seldom assert a conditional "if ..., then ___" when we know the antecedent to be false; but the "modelling" of mathematical logic fit quite well with the use in ordinary mathematics.

The **very** important "context" in mathematics is the following :

> > **Σ⊨φ**;

in this case we say that **Σ** *entails* **φ**. The condition validating the relation of "entailment" is that : every *interpretation* that satisfy (all the sentences in) **Σ** will also satisfy **φ**; or, equivalently, there is **no** interpretation such that all of **Σ** are *true* and **φ** is *false*.

This "context" is commonly used when we assert that some thorem (**φ**) *follows from* a set **Σ** of sentences, e.g.the axioms of a theory.

When **Σ={σ}**, from **σ⊨φ** we have that : **⊨σ→φ**.

This result establish a strict connextion between the *conditional* (→) and the relation of *entailments* (⊨). The two are different relations, but the above link between them is so useful that we "accept" the "not perfect" fit of the conditional with our natural language habits.

Comment: First thank you for the response. I understand some of the benefits of the particular truth table that the material conditional has, but I am more interested in what the relationship is between the material conditional and ordinary language conditionals. I think that what you are trying to get at is that the material conditional, though bearing a resemblance to ordinary language conditionals, was created for very different purposes than those for which the ordinary language conditional was created. But then if logic can't provide insight into ordinary language conditionals what can?

Comment: @leibnewtz - there are a lot of discussions in *Analitycal Philosophy* regarding natural language; my point of view is : natural language is **not** "logically regimented". When in natural language we use "or", it is *exclusive* or *inclusive* ? Both: it depends on the context; for mathematical usages we need "precision"; thus we have "separated" *vel* and *aut*.

Comment: What does this mean in that quote " in the third line only, for 'not' "?

Comment: @barlop - teh usual truth-table for **→** : T-T is T; T-F is F; F-T is T; F-F is T.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so the third line is `F-T is T`  and if we change `is T` to `is F` in the third line only, we get "not".  Not What?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in the case of A->A then the only non-contradictory lines of the truth table are T->T and F->F   So to discuss changing the result of the third line `F->T is T` to `is F`,   even before looking at the result and changing the result, it's a contradictory line.  So it's just at most adding a contradiction into that line that is already contradictory.

Comment: @barlop - sorry; it was a misprint...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for correcting that. Also, you suggest that in the case of the "fourth line"  `F,F is T`  You seem to suggest that if you make the is T, into is F, then the contrapositive is no longer true. I  do agree with my intuitive logic that A->B so ¬B->¬A but I don't see how that is derived from A->B.  particularly how  ¬B->¬A   can be derived when the F,F  line  of A->B  results to true, but cannot be derived when the  F,F line of A->B results to false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If we are trying to fit the contrapositive ¬B->¬A, in the A->B truth table then we'd say ¬B=True and ¬A=True and we'd substiute it into line 1 T,T is T. I think I see.. So if the permutation of ¬B=True ¬A=True results in True. for X->Y X=¬B Y=¬A (as it does).. Then So too, then, B=False A=False X=B Y=A, X->Y must also be true for that case?  I'm not sure though? How would the contrapositive normally be derived?

Comment: @barlop - check it on paper... with a t-t enetred for **A,B** in the order: T-T, T-F; F-T; F-F; the corersponding values for **¬B,¬A** will be: F-F, T-F; F-T; T-T; and the result will not change.

Answer (score 0):

From everyday usage, we have:

1. If we assume A is true and, without making any other assumptions, we
   can infer that B must also be true, then we can infer that A
   implies B is true. There may be intervening premises that were discharged and deactivated. (The Conclusion Rule)
2. If we assume A is true and, without making any other assumptions, we
   can obtain a contradiction, then A must be false. Here, too, there may be intervening premises that were discharged and deactivated. (The Indirect Conclusion
   Rule)

Using these rules from everyday usage, we can prove that for any logical, true-or-false propositions A and B we have: A is true implies that A is false implies B is true. ( A => [~A => B] )

Proof:

1. Let A and B be logical, true-or-false propositions. (Law of Excluded Middle applies)
2. Premise: Suppose A is true.
3. Premise: Suppose A is false. (Assumptions need not be consistent.)
4. Premise: Suppose B is false.
5. Joining (2) and (3), we obtain the contradiction A is true and A is
   false.
6. Applying the Indirect Conclusion Rule, (4) must be false, i.e. B must be true.
7. Applying the Conclusion Rule for (2) and (6), A implies B must be
   true. (Premise on line 4 has been discharged and deactivated.)
8. Applying the Conclusion Rule once more for (1) and (6), we obtain, as required, that A is true implies that A is false implies B is true. (Premise on line 3 has been discharged and deactivated.) ( A => [~A => B] )

From a falsehood, all things follow.

Further details at my blog posting [Material Implication: If Pigs Could Fly](http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html).

Dan

Download my DC Proof 2.0 freeware at http://www.dcproof.com
Visit my Math Blog at http://www.dcproof.wordpress.com